# open a model dialog button and add data to a default sharepoint list form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-foundation, jsom

I have to call a sharepoint list form and pass its data to the current page. I created a modal and function to collect the data with the below code

```
function openDialogAndReceiveData() {
        var options = {
            url: 'https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/ProjectSites/test/Lists/Additional%20Information/NewForm.aspx',
            title: 'test',
            dialogReturnValueCallback: onPopUpCloseCallBackWithData
        };
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    }

    function onPopUpCloseCallBackWithData(result, returnValue) {
        if (result == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
            SP.UI.Status.removeAllStatus(true);
            var sId = SP.UI.Status.addStatus("Data successfully populated to text boxes from Pop-up");
            SP.UI.Status.setStatusPriColor(sId, 'green');
            alert(returnValue[0]);
            //alert(returnValue[1]);
        }
        else if (result == SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel) {
            SP.UI.Status.removeAllStatus(true);
            var sId = SP.UI.Status.addStatus("You have cancelled the Operation !!!");
            SP.UI.Status.setStatusPriColor(sId, 'yellow');
        }
    }
```

on the form i have added the below

```
 <input id="btnClientOk2" type="button" value="Client Side OK and pass Value to Base Page" onclick="closePopupAndPassData()" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

     function closePopupAndPassData() {
         var popData = [];
         popData[0] =$("input[title='Title']").val();
         popData[1] = "test2";
         SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK, popData);
     }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below script in  PopUp Page and call it on submit click:

```
  function closePopupAndPassData() {
     var popData = [];
     popData[0] = document.getElementById('<%= txtPopData1.ClientID %>').value;
     popData[1] = document.getElementById('<%= txtPopData2.ClientID %>').value;
     SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK, popData);
 }
```

This will close the popup and call your onPopUpCloseCallBackWithData method.

Comment: is txtPopData1 and txtPopData2 names of the textboxs from the from the oob form?

Comment: Yes these are the form fields.

Comment: can you share the full code i am not able to do as advised

Comment: i have updated the question with the code you mentioned but it throws an error on alert(popData[0]);